# Extension of List in SwiftUI which returns some View is failing

Tags: swiftui-list

public enum CustomListStyle {
case plain
case inset
case grouped
}

extension List {

```
public func makeListStyle(_ style: CustomListStyle) -> some View {
    switch style {
    case .plain:
        let style = self.listStyle(PlainListStyle())
        return style
    case .inset:
        return self.listStyle(InsetListStyle())
    case .grouped:
        return self.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
    }
}
```

}

error: Function declares an opaque return type 'some View', but the return statements in its body do not have matching underlying types. But in return statements, function is returning some view.

I am trying to implement a custom list style which can be added on list elements and which is platform independent like some styles only work for iOS but not for macOS. I want to pass that list style as a generic parameter before creating the view and there will be no logic inside the view to make it platform dependent.

But compiler gives no error for below code:

extension List {

```
public func makeListStyle(_ listStyle: CustomListStyle) -> some View {
  
        return self.listStyle(.plain)
}
```

}

Comment: Got the answer. Need to use @ViewBuilder.